# How to link a card (tracker Kanban Task) to a git commit?

Tags: git, tuleap

I wanted to know if there is a possibility to link a commit to a card (tracker Kanban Task). Because I wanted to retrieve the commit which resolved the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A card is an artifact and a git commit is also an artifact, so you can reference the two ones by the short name and the number of the artifact. for example, on a git commit you can set in the comment the reference of the bug, bug #23. In this way there will be a crossed reference between the commit and the card.